# Add Class to menu li if href match with the Variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a multilevel menu and I need to highlight the TOP level menu by adding the class `active` to the list.

**[Example on fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3p3wkcos/2/)**

I store a value of link that needs to be active in javascript variable `var activeHREF= '/news/';`

I need jquery that can search through the list `li` and match with the href of in the list if it matches with the anchor element then it should add a `class='active'` to this particular list.

I this this is more efficient way to handle my scenario where I can have up to 3 or 4 multilevel menu's and i need to highlight the Top level Parent menu

A pointer can be good way to start.

Comment: Appreciate everyone reply, +1 for all but more appropriate answer to my question is from 'brian' with two version also.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[**jsFiddle Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/3p3wkcos/7/) with multiple levels of unordered lists.

```
$("a[href='" +activeHREF+ "']").parent().addClass("active")
```

Using filter can do the same thing

```
$('a').filter(function() {
    return $(this).attr('href') == activeHREF;
}).parent().addClass('active');
```

Comment: How can i modify this so it works with anchor text, i tried this `("a").text( +Contact+ ).parent().addClass("active");` but it is not working.

Comment: You can use contains, http://jsfiddle.net/3p3wkcos/10 - loose fitting - will select links that also contain your anchor text ie 'News' and 'The News' when selecting 'News', or a filter http://jsfiddle.net/3p3wkcos/11/ which is more restrictive and only will return links with specified anchor text. Both are good depending on your scenario.

Answer (score 3):

I think you are looking for something like this:

```
$("li:has(a[href='" +activeHREF+ "']):first()").addClass("active")
```

Comment: I think this would be the cleanest way to achieve what you want.

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out, Brian. Edited my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

This how I would do it:

[**Online Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/znhrqe02/)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var activeHREF= '\/contact\/';
    $('li').removeClass('active');
    $('a[href="'+activeHREF+'"]').parent().addClass('active');        
});
```